# Docker hostnames between containers

Tags: linux, docker

I'm running two containers:

- Laravel application (Rest API)
- PHP application (standalone)

The second container is standalone, but makes requests to the first container's API.

The problem i'm having is that the second container would make a request to a development URL e.g. **dev.api.com**

But the API container is not accessible by that URL.

How can I make the API accessible by the standalone PHP app with a specific local URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got two options:

1. prepare /etc/hosts with proper variables that will point your PHP app to the API
2. get third container which will provide DNS service and will resolv ip's to hostnames for your container

Comment: Cheers old bean. I was assuming something like https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydock?

Comment: This will do. I reckon you have loads of solution for that problem, don't know which one is the best. Look at serf from hashicorp too